# How to borrow/add functionality temporarily from/to an object? Any design pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, object

I have a list object - list of nodes. I want to provide "in place sorting/ordering" to the user. User can put any item anywhere in the list. Is there a design pattern where I keep this entire behavior as a package (as an object or whatever) and can borrow it temporarily when the sort mode is needed?

I am doing this in Javascript.

I thought of decorator, but I need to change properties of the original object. Did not feel like the right way to do it. Decorator is suppose to add functionality without modifying the original object.

NEW DETAILS:

I have a better analogy for what I am trying to do. Lets think of a game character. The character lives till the game lives. The character can take on some roles. The role can alter the character's properties, which is permanent. Character can take on one or more roles at one or more times. How would I structure the "Character" and the "Role" in the program.

If Role is like a decorator to the Character, is it good practice to modify private properties of Character bu the Role? Any other way?

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: You can't just attach properties to the lender object's `prototype` and then `lenderObj.sort.call(borrowerObj)`?

Comment: @elclanrs I have the list. The sorting is still in the conceptual stage. I have an object, that needs to stay alive throughout the application. I need a sorter (or any other processor) that can alter properties of the original object but I want to bind that behavior at runtime upon user request, and not provide it as part of the object or its extension.

Comment: @glortho that is what I was planning. What that means is, the lenderObject is actually aware of all the internal working of the borrowerObject, but has no real relationship to that object. I was not sure if it is a good design. Also, this is more like reordering step by step as user wants, not a standard sort.

Comment: I have added a better analogy for what I am trying to do with the list.

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach, you can use a linked list. For each node, you want to keep the node that comes after it. You also want to keep a reference of the first node.

- When the user moves Node A to some place between the first node and the last node, find the node below Node A (Node B), and then set Node B as the next node of Node A.
- If the user moves a node to the end of the list, set the next node to `null`.
- If the user moves a node to the start of the list, update the first node reference.

Finally, when the user save changes, use a recursive function from the first node to create an ordered list of your items.

**Note that you don't actually need to change the original object.** Your Node object should look as simple as:

```
function Node(item, nextNode) {
    this.item = item;
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
}

Node.prototype.getItem = function () {
    return this.item;
};

Node.prototype.getNextNode = function () {
    return this.nextNode;
};

Node.prototype.setNextNode = function (node) {
    this.nextNode = node;
}
```

The `item` property can hold your original object.